# Can't find classpath resource in JAR (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, resources, classpath

I'm attempting to read in a file that I've made available as a resource in the classpath

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("firebase-service-account.json");
```

I've tried accessing the resource through a full path, absolutely, and as a stream and nothings working.

My target file structure looks like this:

[image]

And when I crack open the JAR I can see that resources are properly bundled, although I'm not sure if they're being streamed.

[image]

How can I access my resources?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.BufferedInputStream@27d6c5e0 (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at com.lumos.xlsx_manager.es.da.Firebase.main(Firebase.java:146)
```

Comment: You can't use FileInputStream cause the resulting resources are inside the JAR file. You have to use `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream(".../File.properties")`..

Comment: This worked, would you mind explaining why?

Comment: The location `src/main/resources` will be packaged into the final jar file which means you can't access via File ...So you have to use `class.getResourcesAsStream()` which makes it working for the case on the classpath as well as within the jar....

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, assuming you only need the InputStream and not specifically `FileInputStream`:

```
InputStream serviceAccount = null;
try{
    File f = new File("firebase-service-account.json");
    if (f.exists()){
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(f);
    } else {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("firebase-service-account.json");
        serviceAccount  = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    }

    //Now do whatever you are doing with the InputStream...

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if (serviceAccount  != null) {
            try {
                serviceAccount .close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, couldn't find the files in the JAR. Khmarbaise's suggestion above worked!

Comment: That's very strange - if you check the source code for Class the two methods are identical in that they delegate to methods of the same name in ClassLoader. `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` simply calls `ClassLoader#getResource()` and then `url.openStream()` on the resulting URL if it is non-null (and this is code I have used in multiple places, copy/pasted with your filename/variable names!) - see e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29 and links from there for the sources

Comment: Actually, this is finding the file `f` in my code snippet __does__ exist in your case as they are in the same package, but then FileInputStream cannot access it - in which case, removing the lines which attempt that route and sticking with the `getClass().getResource()` route should work

Comment: @SteveR Using resources consistently is by using `getResourceAsStream()..` this works if you are running your tests and running within the final code where the resources are inside the jar file...both are solved via the classpath...I would suggest to use simpler code...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise - I've never come across it being a problem before, but maybe that was just because the File route never found it, and so the getResource() method always kicked in.  Looking at the URL class javadoc in more detail, that does state that the `openConnection()` method will return a UrlConnection of appropriate type - e.g. HTTPUrlConnection, JarUrlConnection etc... I will leave the answer there as I think the comments discussion is useful!